# Error while running angular js html page on a server

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller

When I'm running my HTML page through a server I'm always getting an error with my angular JavaScript file included. But it runs fine without local server in Mozilla Firefox and Safari but not with Google Chrome (XML errors with Google Chrome).

> //localhost:8000/Users/harsha/Documents/angular%20js/nganimate.js
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (File not found)
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (File not found)
>   angular.js:4361Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=controllerapp&p1=Er…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A264)

**The Screenshot of error message in console**

[image]

Comment: Its unable to find `nganimate.js` thats why its returning a 404, thats probably also why angular errors as the module your trying to inject isn't loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in js file path .

```
//localhost:8000/Users/harsha/Documents/angular%20js/nganimate.js
```

So index file is unable to locate the file.

Comment: That i edited for the post to get privacy :-p. but indeed it shown up in the screen shot

Answer (score 0):

> Users/harsha/Documents/angular%20js/nganimate.js

The path of your server isn't the one from your C: it's relative from where your start your server. If you need us to figure out from where your server start, you need to tell us what is the server.

And if it's the grunt web server, show us your build file.

Comment: I am using a python server by the command python -m SimpleHTTPServer